# what is the difference between ESP register and SS register?

Tags: assembly, x86, memory-segmentation, stack-pointer

I'm just a beginner in Assembly language.
As I know, ESP and SS both refer to stack registers but not quite understand the differences between them.

Comment: You might want to read about [memory segmentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_memory_segmentation).

Comment: SS has no relevance in 32-bit programs.  It maps the full 4 gigabyte virtual memory space, just like DS and ES.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `ESP` register is the 32-bit version of the 16-bit `SP` register, but in the 32-bit architecture, `SS` is irrelevant.  So, let's talk about 16-bit first.  A note about 32-bit is at the end of the post.

In the 16-bit Intel x86 architecture:

- `SS` is the stack-segment register. It identifies the block of memory that will be used for the stack.
- `SP` is the stack pointer register. It points to the precise location within the stack segment which is at any given moment the 'top' of the stack.

---

The 16-bit Intel architecture had a clunky mechanism for implementing 20-bit wide addresses by means of 16-bit 'segments' plus 16-bit 'offsets', so the `SS` register would point to the stack segment, and the `SP` register would hold the actual offset into the stack. We would say that the current stack location was at `SS:SP`.

Naturally, you might wonder how come they were only able to have 20-bit wide addresses instead of 32-bit wide addresses, given that the segment register was 16-bit wide, and the offset register was another 16-bits wide.  Well, this is part of why the architecture was clunky: the actual address represented by the `SS:SP` pair was ***not*** calculated as `(SS << 16) + SP`, instead it was `(SS << 4) + SP`.  This means that the segments had a very high degree of overlap: even though each segment was 65536 bytes long, its start was only 16 bytes away from the start of the previous segment. So, the `segment:offset` address `0:0` represented absolute address `0`, while the `1:0` address represented absolute address `16`. (Apparently they did not believe that anyone would ever need to address more than 20 bits of address space.)

---

### 32-bit

In the 32-bit architecture, none of that matters, because the `ESP` register is large enough to be capable of addressing the entire 32-bit memory address space by itself, with no need for any segment register. So if you are using the `ESP` register you don't have to worry about the `SS` register at all.

Comment: Of course, what Hans Passant wrote is true, and since you are talking about ESP instead of just SP, you are talking about a 32-bit scenario, so you should not need to worry at all about the SS register.

Comment: Actually, to be precise it can be used even on 32 bit CPUs (but on 64 bit), but memory segmentation is not used in practice in any modern OS.